# Password for mobile

Tags: riddle, password

So, there I was, standing in front of my mobile, my best friend Eve pulled one of her infamous puzzling prank...
The mobile is patterned lock and there was a post-it on my mobile, reading :

> What's wrong?
>   Go for it, can you find a password for this lock?
>   This post-it quiz will assist you.
>   But.... possibility is, you won't find it in this.
>   still nothing?
>   Just so you know it is a thing that is missing.
>   :V
>   XO

Can you help me find the pattern?

Note : The pattern lock on mobile accepts only one pattern. And you have to draw it without lifting up a finger(at least it works like this on my mobile)

Comment: What's a patterned lock?

Comment: @mestackoverflow https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmyxUtClCZTdaAfMhfSEAmhf0vB7WUv7sPp6RMXKfNaSdinJYJ this one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is probably

> 4-5-6-3-2-1-7-8-9 or some other way of writing the letter 'E'.

Because

> The letter E doen't appear in the note, and it seems to tell us to look for something which is "missing" or which we "won't find" there.

Comment: at least on android, you can't touch the same node twice, though you can go over a touched node, so removing the duplicate in your answer is effectively the same pattern, but upholding that limitation.

Comment: @DaneAndersen Good point, edited that. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit)'s solution. The "e" pattern could be implemented as below.

It can be traversed in two ways: 1 to 9 (as shown below) or in the reverse (9 to 1)

[image: jgkdfjgkjdk]

Comment: @DaneAnderson  This could be a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Zero is missing from the screen, but there's many ways to write it, depending on where you start from and in what direction. So all the numbers except 5, e.g., starting from 2, clockwise it's 2,3,6,9,8,7,4,1,2; anticlockwise, it's 2,1,4,7,8,9,6,3,2

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The answer is:

> Switch from 1 and 8 with the phone.

Explanation

> `Just so you know it is a thing that is missing.` You said ":V", It's a thing missing, It's a V don't complete like a  missing piece of puzzle.

Comment: Sorry not the answer

Comment: Maybe there's something I'm missing, but I'm genuinely unsure what "switch from 1 and 8 with the phone" means. What were you intending to say?

Answer (score -2):

The hint was "it is missing"
If you dont go that much into meta.
The only possible solution is a word / character.
What jumped me was the "...." before possibility.

> But.... possibility is

-

> So, in my opinion, the hint is "a" as in,"But A possibility is"

But i have no idea how to write that =)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! Would it be possible for you to edit in a detailed explanation as to how this answers the question? Thank you!